# Каким термином можно заменить "предкультуру", чтобы не было сельскохозяйственного духу?

Tags: синонимы, точное-словоупотребление

[Большой толковый словарь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%9F%D0%A0%D0%95%D0%94%D0%9A%D0%A3%D0%9B%D0%AC%D0%A2%D0%A3%D0%A0%D0%90)

> **ПРЕДКУЛЬТУРА,** -ы; *ж.* Сельскохозяйственная культура, предшествующая высеваемой культуре на том же поле. *Кормовая п.
>   Выращивать предкультуры на зелёную массу.*
>
> ---

У меня речь идёт о становящейся, зачаточной культуре, которая не пшено, а

> совокупность достижений человеческого общества в производственной,
>   общественной и духовной жизни.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Какая-нибудь *протокультура* подойдёт? https://naturilife.ru/article/osoznannoe-myshlenie/obrashchenie-k-istokam-protokultura/